# How do I collect a list of properties from related nodes in Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a bunch of `Foo` objects in my graph, and they may have 0 to n related `Bar` objects.  `Bar` objects have a property I'm looking to aggregate against, `baz`. Here's what I've started with:

```
MATCH (f:Foo)--(b:Bar) RETURN f, COLLECT(b.baz)
```

I'm trying to get output that looks like the following:

```
===============================
| f         | COLLECT(b.baz)  |
-------------------------------
| Node(1..) | ["1", "2", "3"] |
| Node(2..) | ["4", "5"]      |
===============================
```

Instead, I'm getting what looks like this:

```
===============================
| f         | COLLECT(b.baz)  |
-------------------------------
| Node(1..) | ["1"]           |
| Node(1..) | ["2"]           |
| etc...                      |
===============================
```

Any insight as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The query looks fine to me. Can you provide a subgraph of your data you're working with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you create an example dataset?
For this dataset your query works fine.

```
CREATE
  (n1:Foo {name: '1'}),
  (a:Bar {name: 'a', baz: 1}),
  (b:Bar {name: 'b', baz: 2}),
  (n1)-[:REL]->(a),
  (n1)-[:REL]->(b)
```

Your query returns the following:

```
MATCH (f:Foo)--(b:Bar)
RETURN f, COLLECT(b.baz)

╒═════════╤══════════════╕
│f        │COLLECT(b.baz)│
╞═════════╪══════════════╡
│{name: 1}│[1, 2]        │
└─────────┴──────────────┘
```

Comment: Pretty sure you're right. I've got a custom written function for displaying the results in an OSGI container, and it's looking like it's output is wrong. Thanks.